# Excluding Ionic components with Vue.js keep-alive

Tags: vue.js

[The Ionic components](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/tree/master/vue) doesn't work with Vue.js' `keep-alive`. So I would like to exclude them. I tried using `exclude="/^ion-*./"` with no luck. The Ionic components doesn't have a name.

How do I exclude the Ionic components from being cached by `keep-alive`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ionic now supports `keep-alive`.

Comment: Are you sure? I have an ion-range component within Vue’s keep-alive component so that when I change views via Vue Router I don’t lose the range setting. I can drag the slider’s handle upon the component’s first load but after leaving that view and then returning to it, the slider value is retained (thanks to keep-alive) but the handle no longer slides. Any idea why not?

I’m using Vue Router 3.1.5, Vue 2.6.10, and @ionic/vue 0.0.4

Comment: Latest Ionic docs (v6) discourages usage of `keep-alive`:
"Because of this special handling, certain Vue Router components such as <keep-alive>, <transition>, and <router-view> should not be used in Ionic Vue applications."
https://ionicframework.com/docs/vue/lifecycle